# Ursina FirstPersonController self.camera_pivot.rotation_x always goes down as mouse is moved slowly (no matter in which direction)

Tags: python, game-development, ursina

I'm fairly new to python and gamedev in general. I've encountered a problem with `Ursinas FirstPersonController`:

Every time i run the app, as soon as i move the mouse slowly the field of view seems to turn upwards (x-Axis) simultaneously as it turns in the direction i move the mouse. (same with the mousepad)

So no matter in what direction i move the mouse gently, the player always tends to looks up.

As i move the mouse faster, the problem gets less apparent, so if i move the mouse in a certain speed down, the player looks down, but if i move the mouse down slowly, the `rotation_x-value` goes down/the player looks up.

Can anyone give me a hint on what is going on here?

The problem occurs with a code as simple as:

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

app = Ursina()
player = FirstPersonController()
Sky()

def input(key):
    if key == 'escape':
        quit()
        
app.run()
```

I've tried this with different codes from github as well, same result

I've also tried changing around with the code of first_person_controller.py without success so far.

Edit: i run on linux mint 21. when i tried the same code with the same setup and pc on win10, the problem didn't occur. So maybe a driver-problem?
I also tried reinstalling VS Code, Anaconda and Ursina without success.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use FirstPersonController in ursina you should use en entity like a ground to keep the player on this entity. Also you have to make this ground entity's collider 'box' to interact with player and keep it over the ground. So you can try this code:

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

app = Ursina()
player = FirstPersonController()
Sky()
ground = Entity(model = "plane", texture="grass", scale = 200, collider="box")

def input(key):
    if key == 'escape':
        quit()
app.run()
```